# Gmail Signature Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, gmail, bookmarklet

I've been using the [Trick Gmail bookmarklet](https://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-trimming-signature/28762/) for a couple years and I love it, but a few months ago it stopped working. I'm trying to fix it, but I am not a coder and have very little idea what I'm doing. Yes, I've tried reaching out to the [developer](https://twitter.com/labnol), but I haven't received any responses.

Here's the original code:

```
javascript:void function()%7Bvar e%3Ddocument.querySelector(".aH1")%3Be%26%26e.click()%3Bvar l%3Ddocument.querySelector("div.gmail_signature"),o%3Ddocument.querySelector("input%5Bname%3D%27composeid%27%5D")%3Bl%26%26o%26%26(l.innerHTML%2B%3D"<br><small style%3D%27color:%23ddd%27>Ref %23"%2Bo.value%2B"</small>")%7D()%3B
```

I've dug through the gmail code using inspect element and looked at several guides at w3 schools, but I'm completely at a loss.

If you're not familiar with the bookmarklet, basically it clicks the three little dots that mark trimmed content when composing a reply and then appends a very lightly colored text behind the signature making it unique (so your signature doesn't get trimmed).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the following bookmarklet seems to work fine:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var e = document.querySelectorAll(".ajT")[document.querySelectorAll(".ajT").length - 1];
    e&&e.click();
    var l = document.querySelector("div.gmail_signature"), o = document.querySelector("input[name='composeid']");
    l&&o&&(l.innerHTML+="<br><small style='color:#ddd'>Ref #"+o.value+"</small>");  
})();
```